# PHP Know if category exist in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, list, addition, categories

I am writing a simple script php.
This script has to know if a specified category passed via $_get exist in wordpress cms.

exist.php?cat=xxx

I have read this but I am not sure if it can help me.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

Can anyone help me?
How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/how-do-i-determine-if-a-category-exists-by-id

Comment: Have you looked at ways to access wordpress functions in external PHP Pages? http://www.wordpress-master.com/wordpress-functions-external-php-pages.html

Comment: thanks I think they can close this post....I don't know http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you are trying to access it from a separate PHP file, connect to the WordPress database in your script and run this query:

```
<?php
include 'wp-config.php';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` TT RIGHT JOIN `wp_terms` TE ON TT.`term_id` = TE.`term_id` WHERE TT.`taxonomy` = 'category' AND TE.`name` = :category" );
$stmt->bindParam( ':category', $_GET['cat'] );
$stmt->execute();

if ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // It exists
} else {
    // It does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use get_categories to get all categories in an array, and then use in_array to find it category exists. You can then use the same category id to get more information about the category too. 
Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Source_File
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Example:

```
<?php 
$cat_list = get_categories(); 

if (in_array($_GET['cat'], $cat_list)) {
// exists
} else {
// does not exists
}    
?>
```